# Perl cut exact part of the string and store the first delimiter

Tags: perl, split

Let say I have a variable in this format:

```
my $time1 = "2021-01-02T11:12:00+01:00";
```

I would like to get the part of the string from `+` or the last `-` to the last `:` and also the first delimiter which should be a `+` or `-`

What I tried so far:

```
print (split(/\+/, $time))[0];
```

but it will then print:

```
01:00
```

instead of:

```
01
```

and also doesn't store the first delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are parsing an ISO 8601 datetime string, you might consider using something that is smart about datetime strings.

Date::Parse can give you the timezone offset in seconds and you can convert that to integer hours (or whatever else you might want to do):

```
use v5.10;
use Date::Parse;

my $datetime = '2021-01-02T11:12:00-01:30';

my @t = Date::Parse::strptime( $datetime );

say "Time zone offset in seconds: $t[-2]";
printf '%02d', abs($t[-2])/3600;
```

Otherwise, Wes's answer is probably what I'd do.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is more accurate and simple. Just FYI: the array's element is not -2 it is -1 (tested with it, it gives me the right result.

Comment: It might depend on the Date::Parse version. For -1 I get the century value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions to extract that type of information more easily:

```perl
my $time1 = "2021-01-02T11:12:00+01:00";
($hourpart) = ($time1 =~ /.*[+-](\d{2}):\d{2}$/);
print($hourpart,"\n");
```

(you can use split too, but it would require multiple split calls)

If you're **positive** that the length won't change (often true for fixed format date strings), you can try `substr` instead too:

```perl
print(substr($time1, 20, 2),"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please investigate following code snippet which with `split` fills a hash. Then you can access any part of timestamp as your heart desires.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $time1 = "2021-01-02T11:12:00+01:00";

my $date_time;
my @fields = qw/year month day hour minute second hour_tz minute_tz/;

$date_time->@{@fields} = split("[-+:T]",$time1);

say "Timestamp: " . $time1;
say Dumper($date_time);

my $tz;
$tz->@{qw/sign hour minute/} = $time1 =~ /([-+])(\d+):(\d+)\z/;

say Dumper($tz);
```

Output

```
Timestamp: 2021-01-02T11:12:00+01:00
$VAR1 = {
          'second' => '00',
          'day' => '02',
          'hour_tz' => '01',
          'year' => '2021',
          'minute' => '12',
          'hour' => '11',
          'month' => '01',
          'minute_tz' => '00'
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'hour' => '01',
          'sign' => '+',
          'minute' => '00'
        };
```